# Ubuntu 22.04.4 WiFi became unstable after some system update (and maybe install of some keyboard input language)

Tags: wireless, 22.04

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.4(dual boot with win11) on a labtop with wifi7 from Intel.

Everything was doing fine until I blindly trust a system software update from Ubuntu software update. Right after the update the computer was still having stable WiFi connection, in which I installed Chinese language through language and region in setting and had a zoom meeting. But after the computer restart, the WiFi will only be connected for like a minute then after that it does not work then after a while it may work.

If I click WiFi setting it says the NetworkManager is off. So I tried the following:

1. set WiFi power management to 2 (disable)
2. reinstall NetworkManager and restart.
   Both does not work.

The following is a dump of the output of `dmesg -w` when the network go from working to not working.

```
[  970.097087] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  970.097091] Invalid rxb from HW 0
[  970.097136] WARNING: CPU: 21 PID: 818 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/rx.c:1489 iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x3ce/0x640 [iwlwifi]
[  970.097171] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg snd_ctl_led snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_sof_probes snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio nvidia_uvm(PO) intel_uncore_frequency intel_uncore_frequency_common bnep x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp btusb btrtl uvcvideo btbcm videobuf2_vmalloc btintel uvc btmtk videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 bluetooth videodev videobuf2_common ecdh_generic mc ecc usbhid snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel snd_sof_intel_hda_mlink soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_sof_utils snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_bus snd_soc_core coretemp snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_compress joydev ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_intel_sdw_acpi iwlmvm snd_hda_codec irqbypass snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep
[  970.097209]  polyval_clmulni polyval_generic mac80211 nvidia_drm(PO) snd_pcm ghash_clmulni_intel sha256_ssse3 snd_seq_midi sha1_ssse3 nvidia_modeset(PO) i915 libarc4 snd_seq_midi_event aesni_intel snd_rawmidi drm_buddy crypto_simd nvidia(PO) ttm binfmt_misc cryptd snd_seq iwlwifi cmdlinepart drm_display_helper snd_seq_device mei_pxp snd_timer mei_hdcp rapl spi_nor input_leds nls_iso8859_1 intel_rapl_msr gpio_keys cec intel_cstate cfg80211 wmi_bmof serio_raw rc_core msi_wmi mtd processor_thermal_device_pci mei_me processor_thermal_device snd hid_multitouch drm_kms_helper processor_thermal_rfim mei processor_thermal_mbox soundcore processor_thermal_rapl i2c_algo_bit intel_rapl_common mac_hid int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_thermal_rel soc_button_array sparse_keymap acpi_tad acpi_pad sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 nvme nvme_core nvme_common hid_generic rtsx_pci_sdmmc crc32_pclmul thunderbolt psmouse r8169 spi_intel_pci i2c_i801
[  970.097256]  rtsx_pci spi_intel i2c_smbus intel_lpss_pci realtek intel_lpss xhci_pci vmd xhci_pci_renesas idma64 i2c_hid_acpi i2c_hid hid video wmi pinctrl_alderlake
[  970.097266] CPU: 21 PID: 818 Comm: irq/202-iwlwifi Tainted: P        W  O    6.5.0-25-generic #25~22.04.1-Ubuntu
[  970.097269] Hardware name: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Raider GE68 HX 14VIG/MS-15M1, BIOS E15M1IMS.706 11/02/2023
[  970.097270] RIP: 0010:iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x3ce/0x640 [iwlwifi]
[  970.097292] Code: da 8b 43 34 83 43 30 08 83 e8 08 89 43 34 e9 70 fe ff ff 44 89 f0 89 d6 45 89 e6 41 89 c4 48 c7 c7 a8 5b 4c c4 e8 42 54 ca d9 <0f> 0b 4c 89 ff e8 e8 3b ff ff 8b 55 d4 85 d2 0f 95 c0 41 21 c6 e9
[  970.097294] RSP: 0018:ffffbd67c055ce18 EFLAGS: 00010246
[  970.097296] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff9d4b72785040 RCX: 0000000000000000
[  970.097297] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
[  970.097298] RBP: ffffbd67c055ce78 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[  970.097299] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 000000000000100d
[  970.097300] R13: 0000000000000015 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff9d4b4ab30028
[  970.097301] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9d5abf940000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  970.097303] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  970.097304] CR2: 000056be01a73b00 CR3: 000000036243a000 CR4: 0000000000750ee0
[  970.097306] PKRU: 55555554
[  970.097307] Call Trace:
[  970.097308]  <IRQ>
[  970.097310]  ? show_regs+0x6d/0x80
[  970.097315]  ? __warn+0x89/0x160
[  970.097319]  ? iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x3ce/0x640 [iwlwifi]
[  970.097342]  ? report_bug+0x17e/0x1b0
[  970.097346]  ? handle_bug+0x46/0x90
[  970.097348]  ? exc_invalid_op+0x18/0x80
[  970.097350]  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1b/0x20
[  970.097354]  ? iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x3ce/0x640 [iwlwifi]
[  970.097376]  ? iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x3ce/0x640 [iwlwifi]
[  970.097397]  ? enqueue_task+0x10/0x1a0
[  970.097400]  iwl_pcie_napi_poll_msix+0x32/0x100 [iwlwifi]
[  970.097422]  __napi_poll+0x30/0x1f0
[  970.097425]  net_rx_action+0x181/0x2e0
[  970.097427]  ? __irq_wake_thread+0x42/0x50
[  970.097430]  __do_softirq+0xd9/0x349
[  970.097434]  ? __pfx_irq_thread_fn+0x10/0x10
[  970.097436]  do_softirq.part.0+0x41/0x80
[  970.097439]  </IRQ>
[  970.097440]  <TASK>
[  970.097441]  __local_bh_enable_ip+0x72/0x80
[  970.097443]  iwl_pcie_irq_rx_msix_handler+0xd7/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[  970.097465]  irq_thread_fn+0x21/0x70
[  970.097467]  irq_thread+0xf8/0x1c0
[  970.097469]  ? __pfx_irq_thread_dtor+0x10/0x10
[  970.097471]  ? __pfx_irq_thread+0x10/0x10
[  970.097473]  kthread+0xef/0x120
[  970.097476]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[  970.097479]  ret_from_fork+0x44/0x70
[  970.097482]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[  970.097485]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[  970.097492]  </TASK>
[  970.097493] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[  970.097525] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  970.097526] Invalid rxb from HW 0
[  970.097538] WARNING: CPU: 21 PID: 818 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/rx.c:1489 iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x3ce/0x640 [iwlwifi]
[  970.097559] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg snd_ctl_led snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_sof_probes snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio nvidia_uvm(PO) intel_uncore_frequency intel_uncore_frequency_common bnep x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp btusb btrtl uvcvideo btbcm videobuf2_vmalloc btintel uvc btmtk videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 bluetooth videodev videobuf2_common ecdh_generic mc ecc usbhid snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel snd_sof_intel_hda_mlink soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_sof_utils snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_bus snd_soc_core coretemp snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_compress joydev ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg kvm snd_intel_sdw_acpi iwlmvm snd_hda_codec irqbypass snd_hda_core crct10dif_pclmul snd_hwdep
[  970.097587]  polyval_clmulni polyval_generic mac80211 nvidia_drm(PO) snd_pcm ghash_clmulni_intel sha256_ssse3 snd_seq_midi sha1_ssse3 nvidia_modeset(PO) i915 libarc4 snd_seq_midi_event aesni_intel snd_rawmidi drm_buddy crypto_simd nvidia(PO) ttm binfmt_misc cryptd snd_seq iwlwifi cmdlinepart drm_display_helper snd_seq_device mei_pxp snd_timer mei_hdcp rapl spi_nor input_leds nls_iso8859_1 intel_rapl_msr gpio_keys cec intel_cstate cfg80211 wmi_bmof serio_raw rc_core msi_wmi mtd processor_thermal_device_pci mei_me processor_thermal_device snd hid_multitouch drm_kms_helper processor_thermal_rfim mei processor_thermal_mbox soundcore processor_thermal_rapl i2c_algo_bit intel_rapl_common mac_hid int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_thermal_rel soc_button_array sparse_keymap acpi_tad acpi_pad sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 nvme nvme_core nvme_common hid_generic rtsx_pci_sdmmc crc32_pclmul thunderbolt psmouse r8169 spi_intel_pci i2c_i801
[  970.097620]  rtsx_pci spi_intel i2c_smbus intel_lpss_pci realtek intel_lpss xhci_pci vmd xhci_pci_renesas idma64 i2c_hid_acpi i2c_hid hid video wmi pinctrl_alderlake
[  970.097627] CPU: 21 PID: 818 Comm: irq/202-iwlwifi Tainted: P        W  O    6.5.0-25-generic #25~22.04.1-Ubuntu
[  970.097628] Hardware name: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Raider GE68 HX 14VIG/MS-15M1, BIOS E15M1IMS.706 11/02/2023
[  970.097629] RIP: 0010:iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x3ce/0x640 [iwlwifi]
[  970.097649] Code: da 8b 43 34 83 43 30 08 83 e8 08 89 43 34 e9 70 fe ff ff 44 89 f0 89 d6 45 89 e6 41 89 c4 48 c7 c7 a8 5b 4c c4 e8 42 54 ca d9 <0f> 0b 4c 89 ff e8 e8 3b ff ff 8b 55 d4 85 d2 0f 95 c0 41 21 c6 e9
[  970.097650] RSP: 0018:ffffbd67c055ce18 EFLAGS: 00010246
[  970.097652] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff9d4b72785040 RCX: 0000000000000000
[  970.097653] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
[  970.097654] RBP: ffffbd67c055ce78 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[  970.097654] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000001014
[  970.097655] R13: 0000000000000008 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff9d4b4ab30028
[  970.097656] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9d5abf940000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  970.097657] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  970.097658] CR2: 000056be01a73b00 CR3: 000000036243a000 CR4: 0000000000750ee0
[  970.097660] PKRU: 55555554
[  970.097660] Call Trace:
[  970.097661]  <IRQ>
[  970.097662]  ? show_regs+0x6d/0x80
[  970.097664]  ? __warn+0x89/0x160
[  970.097667]  ? iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x3ce/0x640 [iwlwifi]
[  970.097687]  ? report_bug+0x17e/0x1b0
[  970.097689]  ? handle_bug+0x46/0x90
[  970.097690]  ? exc_invalid_op+0x18/0x80
[  970.097691]  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1b/0x20
[  970.097695]  ? iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x3ce/0x640 [iwlwifi]
[  970.097714]  ? iwl_pcie_rx_handle+0x3ce/0x640 [iwlwifi]
[  970.097734]  iwl_pcie_napi_poll_msix+0x32/0x100 [iwlwifi]
[  970.097754]  __napi_poll+0x30/0x1f0
[  970.097756]  net_rx_action+0x181/0x2e0
[  970.097758]  __do_softirq+0xd9/0x349
[  970.097761]  ? __pfx_irq_thread_fn+0x10/0x10
[  970.097763]  do_softirq.part.0+0x41/0x80
[  970.097765]  </IRQ>
[  970.097766]  <TASK>
[  970.097767]  __local_bh_enable_ip+0x72/0x80
[  970.097769]  iwl_pcie_irq_rx_msix_handler+0xd7/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[  970.097789]  irq_thread_fn+0x21/0x70
[  970.097791]  irq_thread+0xf8/0x1c0
[  970.097793]  ? __pfx_irq_thread_dtor+0x10/0x10
[  970.097795]  ? __pfx_irq_thread+0x10/0x10
[  970.097797]  kthread+0xef/0x120
[  970.097799]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[  970.097802]  ret_from_fork+0x44/0x70
[  970.097804]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[  970.097806]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[  970.097808]  </TASK>
[  970.097809] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[  970.097932] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[  970.098127] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[  970.098129] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
[  970.098130] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 83.ec13314b.0 gl-c0-fm-c0-83.ucode
[  970.098131] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN      
[  970.098133] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00008E00 | trm_hw_status0
[  970.098134] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[  970.098134] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x002C280A | branchlink2
[  970.098135] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00009328 | interruptlink1
[  970.098136] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00009328 | interruptlink2
[  970.098136] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x0000F46C | data1
[  970.098137] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x01000000 | data2
[  970.098138] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[  970.098139] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x764028F9 | beacon time
[  970.098139] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xCDA1F93E | tsf low
[  970.098140] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x000000E2 | tsf hi
[  970.098141] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00002895 | time gp1
[  970.098141] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x031A8F05 | time gp2
[  970.098142] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[  970.098143] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000053 | uCode version major
[  970.098144] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xEC13314B | uCode version minor
[  970.098144] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000472 | hw version
[  970.098145] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00C80002 | board version
[  970.098146] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x040E001C | hcmd
[  970.098146] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xE6F28000 | isr0
[  970.098147] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x01440000 | isr1
[  970.098148] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x48F0000A | isr2
[  970.098148] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00C0040F | isr3
[  970.098149] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x08200000 | isr4
[  970.098150] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x0402001C | last cmd Id
[  970.098150] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x0000F46C | wait_event
[  970.098151] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x008E00C4 | l2p_control
[  970.098152] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x0001B434 | l2p_duration
[  970.098152] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x0100004A | l2p_mhvalid
[  970.098153] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000018 | l2p_addr_match
[  970.098154] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[  970.098154] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[  970.098155] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x0000C098 | flow_handler
[  970.098440] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[  970.098441] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
[  970.098442] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 83.ec13314b.0 gl-c0-fm-c0-83.ucode
[  970.098443] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN      
[  970.098444] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x000002F0 | trm_hw_status0
[  970.098444] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[  970.098445] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x002C280A | branchlink2
[  970.098446] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x002B79C6 | interruptlink1
[  970.098447] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x002B79C6 | interruptlink2
[  970.098447] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x002A50FC | data1
[  970.098448] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x01000000 | data2
[  970.098449] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[  970.098449] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x764028F9 | beacon time
[  970.098450] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xCDA1F93F | tsf low
[  970.098451] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x000000E2 | tsf hi
[  970.098451] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[  970.098452] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x031A8F05 | time gp2
[  970.098453] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[  970.098454] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000053 | uCode version major
[  970.098454] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xEC13314B | uCode version minor
[  970.098455] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000472 | hw version
[  970.098456] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00C80002 | board version
[  970.098456] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x8043FC4D | hcmd
[  970.098457] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00020000 | isr0
[  970.098458] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[  970.098459] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x48F00002 | isr2
[  970.098459] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00C0001C | isr3
[  970.098460] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[  970.098461] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[  970.098461] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x002A50FC | wait_event
[  970.098462] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[  970.098463] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[  970.098463] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x003C0000 | l2p_mhvalid
[  970.098464] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000007 | l2p_addr_match
[  970.098465] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000028 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[  970.098466] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[  970.098466] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x0000C098 | flow_handler
[  970.098700] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[  970.098700] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 7
[  970.098701] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x20000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST
[  970.098702] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[  970.098703] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xC00809B0 | umac branchlink2
[  970.098704] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x802698E4 | umac interruptlink1
[  970.098704] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x0109531E | umac interruptlink2
[  970.098705] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x01000000 | umac data1
[  970.098706] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x0109531E | umac data2
[  970.098707] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[  970.098707] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000053 | umac major
[  970.098708] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xEC13314B | umac minor
[  970.098709] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x031A8EF9 | frame pointer
[  970.098709] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xD00D625C | stack pointer
[  970.098710] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x0092019C | last host cmd
[  970.098711] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000400 | isr status reg
[  970.098963] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: TCM1 status:
[  970.098964] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000070 | error ID
[  970.098965] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x0000184E | tcm branchlink2
[  970.098965] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00001C44 | tcm interruptlink1
[  970.098966] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00001C44 | tcm interruptlink2
[  970.098967] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x40000000 | tcm data1
[  970.098968] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | tcm data2
[  970.098968] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | tcm data3
[  970.098969] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x000018AC | tcm log PC
[  970.098970] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00803FF0 | tcm frame pointer
[  970.098970] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00803F4C | tcm stack pointer
[  970.098971] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | tcm msg ID
[  970.098972] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x4000001F | tcm ISR status
[  970.098972] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00008E00 | tcm HW status[0]
[  970.098973] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | tcm HW status[1]
[  970.098974] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00018034 | tcm HW status[2]
[  970.098975] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x40008340 | tcm HW status[3]
[  970.098976] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | tcm HW status[4]
[  970.098976] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | tcm SW status[0]
[  970.099227] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: RCM1 status:
[  970.099228] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000070 | error ID
[  970.099229] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00001B9E | rcm branchlink2
[  970.099229] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00002178 | rcm interruptlink1
[  970.099230] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00002178 | rcm interruptlink2
[  970.099231] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x20000000 | rcm data1
[  970.099232] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | rcm data2
[  970.099232] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | rcm data3
[  970.099233] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00001C00 | rcm log PC
[  970.099234] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00803FF0 | rcm frame pointer
[  970.099235] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00803F4C | rcm stack pointer
[  970.099235] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | rcm msg ID
[  970.099236] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x20060000 | rcm ISR status
[  970.099237] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x005601CE | frame HW status
[  970.099237] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | LMAC-to-RCM request mbox
[  970.099238] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000041 | RCM-to-LMAC request mbox
[  970.099239] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x000000C4 | MAC header control
[  970.099240] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xC4846590 | MAC header addr1 low
[  970.099240] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x0100004A | MAC header info
[  970.099241] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | MAC header error
[  970.099491] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: TCM2 status:
[  970.099492] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000070 | error ID
[  970.099493] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x0000184E | tcm branchlink2
[  970.099493] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00001C44 | tcm interruptlink1
[  970.099494] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00001C44 | tcm interruptlink2
[  970.099495] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x40000000 | tcm data1
[  970.099496] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | tcm data2
[  970.099496] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | tcm data3
[  970.099497] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x000018AC | tcm log PC
[  970.099498] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00803FF0 | tcm frame pointer
[  970.099498] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00803F4C | tcm stack pointer
[  970.099499] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | tcm msg ID
[  970.099500] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x60000000 | tcm ISR status
[  970.099501] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x000002F0 | tcm HW status[0]
[  970.099501] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | tcm HW status[1]
[  970.099502] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | tcm HW status[2]
[  970.099503] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00008000 | tcm HW status[3]
[  970.099504] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | tcm HW status[4]
[  970.099504] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | tcm SW status[0]
[  970.099756] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: RCM2 status:
[  970.099757] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000070 | error ID
[  970.099758] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00001B9E | rcm branchlink2
[  970.099758] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00002178 | rcm interruptlink1
[  970.099759] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00002178 | rcm interruptlink2
[  970.099760] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x20000000 | rcm data1
[  970.099761] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | rcm data2
[  970.099761] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | rcm data3
[  970.099765] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00001C00 | rcm log PC
[  970.099765] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00803FF0 | rcm frame pointer
[  970.099766] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00803F4C | rcm stack pointer
[  970.099767] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | rcm msg ID
[  970.099768] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x20000000 | rcm ISR status
[  970.099769] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00020400 | frame HW status
[  970.099769] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | LMAC-to-RCM request mbox
[  970.099770] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | RCM-to-LMAC request mbox
[  970.099771] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | MAC header control
[  970.099772] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | MAC header addr1 low
[  970.099772] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x003C0000 | MAC header info
[  970.099773] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | MAC header error
[  970.099990] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[  970.099991] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[  970.100000] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x0000FCAE | IML/ROM data1
[  970.100011] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[  970.100018] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[  970.100021] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x67A00000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[  970.100026] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x80B00004 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[  970.100031] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00550000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[  970.100036] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x0000AA14 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[  970.100041] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x0000000F | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[  970.100046] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[  970.100051] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x02001910 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[  970.100056] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x02001910 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[  970.100061] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x02001910 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[  970.100068] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x02001910 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[  970.100076] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00001BEF | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[  970.100085] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[  970.100090] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00550000 | FSEQ_PREV_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[  970.100095] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00B00004 | FSEQ_WIFI_FSEQ_VERSION
[  970.100100] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x00B00004 | FSEQ_BT_FSEQ_VERSION
[  970.100105] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x0000005F | FSEQ_CLASS_TP_VERSION
[  970.100116] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: UMAC CURRENT PC: 0x8026935a
[  970.100122] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: LMAC1 CURRENT PC: 0xd0
[  970.100127] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: LMAC2 CURRENT PC: 0xd0
[  970.100132] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: UMAC CURRENT PC 1: 0x80269358
[  970.100136] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: TCM1 CURRENT PC: 0xd0
[  970.100141] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: RCM1 CURRENT PC: 0xd0
[  970.100146] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: RCM2 CURRENT PC: 0xd0
[  970.100152] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Function Scratch status:
[  970.100153] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: 0x01010100 | Func Scratch
[  970.242330] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
[  970.242334] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
```

Thanks ahead!

PS: I think the WiFi hardware is working because it is doing fine with win11

Comment: A bug was created : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-6.5/+bug/2057484 I have issue too with MLO. It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same exact issue. I suspect it is due to `linux-firmware` (I have loaded version 83.ec13314b.0 gl-c0-fm-c0-83.ucode). Weirdly, the same issue is on 23.10 AND 22.04 after doing an update. This is wifi7 on a Z790 board/i9-14900K/WiFi7 AX211.

What finally solved the issue is downgrading the kernel from `linux-6.5.0-25` to `linux-6.5.0-18`.

Comment: Thanks I’ll try

Comment: You saved my life, btw how did you find the solution?

Comment: I wasted the whole day yesterday trying to solve it... tried everything, and this one worked. I'm ashamed of telling you the other attempts I did